# Hide input[type="month"] clear button in mobile chrome/safari

Tags: css, html

I made web application for mobile.
I need to remove clear button when open input[type="month"] popup.
I tried many way that i found in stackoverflow, but failed.
I tried `input[type="month"]::-webkit-clear-button` but didn't work.
I also tried add `required="required"` attribute, but didn't work.

```css
input[type="month"]::-webkit-clear-button {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month" required="required">
```

Is there any other solution? or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Your question is unclear, however it seems you should use Javascript/Jquery to achieve this, here is a tip<script> $(#month).( function .... </script>

Comment: try Using `#month` in css

Comment: @sjdm I mean 'Hide input[type=“month”] clear button in mobile chrome/safari'.

Comment: @Dr.Strange I tried but still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the "Clear" next to "Done" (as seen below), then unfortunately it is not possible. The keyboard(s) for Mobile Safari are fixed and the only control you have are the "variants" that you can show based on `[type]` attributes.

[image]